# Is there a way to prevent automatic newline on python command line?

Tags: python, command-line, game-engine

I am making a command line game engine in python. However, when I attempt to print a command, it newlines and creates a jittery frame.

Adding the `end` attribute bogs down my computer and nearly crashes the shell. The dupe uses `sys.stdout.write('') newline sys.stdout.flush` or `print'',` or `print('',end='')`. all bog down shell and crash it. `print('')` doesn't bog down though which is weird.

```
#this is enough code to demonstrate the problem
while true:
    print('                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         =                                                                              ===                                                                            =====                                                                          =======                                                                        =========                                                                      ===========                                                                    =============    YYYYYYYYYYY                                                 ================================================================================')
#crash issue
import sys
while True:
    sys.stdout.write('mooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I expect the screen to fill, instead it wobbles up and down.

Comment: You probably want to use a library that offers better control over the screen buffer, e.g. `python_prompt_toolkit` or `asciimatics`. Also, for your specific problem, you may want to use `print(text, end='')` (if I understood correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I’m thinking you do not want to print a new line with each call to the `print()` function.

If so, the print function has an optional argument `end`, that is set by default as `\n` (this, creating a new line if not specified otherwise). If you don’t want this to happen, you can simply use the print function as:

```
print(your_argument, end=“”)
```

Replacing `your_argument` with whatever you want to print out.

Comment: this works, however it bogs down the terminal.